# VS 2017 RC cannot find cordova tools

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, taco

after several unistalls and reinstalls processes of VS 2017 I'm still getting the following error (translated from spanish) when I try to compile for chrome emulator a new and empty project in vs 2017 RC:

```
MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLDErr_Build_ToolsetInstallation: Could not find the target tool set on the disk.
```

I've tried also to perform repair processes but the error still persists. Of course I've checked that android SDK, node, etc. are installed and the environment variables have the correct name and path.

Does anyone know how can force to find cordova tools or whatever it is looking for?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck with this?  I just got this same message with full release version from this week...

Comment: I have the same here to. On a complete fresh Windows 10 machine. 1703 build. It worked on a clean Win10 machine with  1607

Comment: Same error here. Anything new?

Answer (score 3):

In my case this worked:

Go to visual studio installer(type it in windows start menu).

Choose to modify your installation of Visual Studio.

Go to indivudual components.

Choose to add cordova 6.3.1(at this moment) toolset.

Install and try to build your project.